# If the government wants to hide what happened during the void history why won't they just destroy the Poneglyph stone instead?

Tags: one-piece

The world government has been chasing Nico Robin for reading history of Void Century on Poneglyph stones. But why won't they just destroy it so the problem is solved?

Comment: I don't read One Piece, but I guess it's natural to keep them for historical reason, and for future research.

Comment: I don't think government has this reason. As clearly they are against research and studies regarding Poneglyph stones to hide the history during Void Century. A good example is how they annihilate the whole island of Ohara for studying these stones. Only Nico Robin is the survivor that's why she has a high bounty when she was still a kid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Poneglyph), Poneglyph is indestructible.

> **The blocks have no real power themselves, apart from their indestructibility; it has been stated that not even explosives could leave a scratch on these stones.** However, the words they contain have the power to change the world.
>
> Each one tells a piece of history long forgotten. This history
> includes mentions of (at least) three weapons of mass destruction:
> Pluton, Poseidon and Uranus. There are two types of poneglyphs: those
> that carry information about how to reach the other poneglyphs and
> those that carry the records of the "True History". Only when the
> stones are read as one will they fill in the Void Century of the
> world. **In the eyes of the World Government, they are dangerous
> artifacts and despite declaring the stones dangerous because of the
> weapons, the reality is that the ideals of the fallen Kingdom written
> on some of the stones are far more dangerous then any of the weapons.**

Because the Government stated that Poneglyph are dangerous artifacts and the blocks also indestructible, the Government prefer to kill peoples in Ohara rather than destroy the Poneglyph.